# Probability of choosing from population with 10% trait

Tags: probability

In a large city, 10% of the population has green eyes

i) What is the probability that exactly two of a group of 20 randomly chosen people have green eyes?

ii) What is the probability that more than two of a group of 20 randomly chosen people have green eyes?

Help please, I'm stumped as to how to approach this question

Answer (score 1):

a) For exactly two to have green eyes, 18 must have non-green eyes. Remember the order doesn't matter, therefore we have $20 \choose 2$ ways the two people can be distributed amongst the 20 people. The probability is $$(0.1^2)(0.9^{18}) \times \binom{20}{2}$$

Now for the second part, more than 2 people having green eyes, means 3 or 4 or 5 etc. have green eyes. The **complimentary** event would be if 2 or 1 or 0 people have green eyes. So you could find the probabilities of 2, 1, 0 people with green eyes, add them together and then subtract from 1. I hope you are familiar with that. If not, do ask.

Comment: Ohh, I understand now. Thank you ^.^